# Scraping specific dd item using Python beautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract specific 'dd' element from the website using Python

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
           'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.ranger5g.com/forum/threads/pre-collision-assist.3239"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


vehicle=[]

for i in soup.findAll("div", class_="message-userExtras"):
    for item in soup.find_all("dd")[::-1]:
        vehicle.append(item.get_text())
print(vehicle)
```

I am trying to extract only vehicle list from the url and my output should be as follows

```
2019 Ford Ranger XLT FX4
2019 Ford Ranger Lariat FX4, 1973 Mercury Capri
Tahoe/Tundra/Fusion
2019 Ford Ranger Lariat - Saber; 2014 GMC Terrain
```

But my result is not what I expect it to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression re and search the `dt` tag with text `Vehicle` and then find the next `dd` tag.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
           'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.ranger5g.com/forum/threads/pre-collision-assist.3239"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all("div",class_='message-userExtras'):
    print(item.find('dt',text=re.compile("Vehicle")).find_next('dd').text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
2019 Ford Ranger XLT FX4
2019 Ford Ranger Lariat FX4, 1973 Mercury Capri
Tahoe/Tundra/Fusion
2019 Ford Ranger Lariat - Saber; 2014 GMC Terrain
2019 Ford Ranger Lariat FX4, 1973 Mercury Capri
2019 Ranger Lariat - 2019 Honda CRV Touring
2019 Ford Ranger XLT FX4
2019 Ford Ranger Lariat FX4, 1973 Mercury Capri
2019 Ranger Lariat SuperCab
2019 Ranger Lariat
Ranger Lariat
2019 Ford Ranger Lariat
Ranger Lariat
Ranger Lariat
2019 Ranger XLT 301A SuperCrew 4X4 2015 Ecoboost Mustang 50 Year Appereance Package convertible
```

Comment: hi there - good evening dear Anonymouls13 and KunduK - many thanks to you both - i have re-runned the code on my ATOM-editor and all works great. I am happy - since i am   fairly new to Python and i want to digg deeper in all that things - have a great day and keep up the great project